# Laravel 5.4 Uploading files: Same Image is different in two Forms

Tags: php, laravel

I have two separate forms, in two controllers,for two separate things (Products and users). Laravel has a default way to upload a file so i resorted to it.

When a product is created, it saves the image of the product in the disk with no problem. However, when i want to save the Avatar of the user, it says that the mime file does not exists.

The codes for each function:

Upload a product image

```
public static function uploadProduct(Request $request, Object $object){
     $file=$request->file('imagen');
     var_dump($file);
    //die(); <-Used it for debugging
     $ext=$file->extension();
     $path=$file->storeAs($object->nombre,'producto'.$request->numeroProd.".".$ext,'public');
     return $path;
}
```

Upload the avatar

```
public static function saveAvatar(Request $request){
    $file=$request->file('imagen');
    var_dump($file);
    $ext=$file->extension();
    $usuario=Auth::user();
    $nombre=$usuario->username;
    $idSitio=$usuario->sitio_id;
    $sitio=Sitio::find($idSitio);

    $path=$file->storeAs($sitio->nombre,$nombre.'.'.$ext);
    $usuario->fotografia=$path;
    $usuario->save();
}
```

Confused, i added some var dumps  and uploadedthe same file to check how the file was getting in the backend. and i found the following:

File on the Product Upload:

```
object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#403 (8) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(16) "3-2-lion-png.png"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(1581953)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["hashName":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD60F.tmp"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(11) "phpD60F.tmp"
}
```

File on the avatar upload

```
 object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#410 (8) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(16) "3-2-lion-png.png"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(2)
  ["hashName":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

The Mime type for the same image changed...but why? how?
Any idea what's gooing on?

---

CLOSING THIS: there was a upload size limit in the image. Was not informed of that

Comment: Clearly avatar file is not actually being uploaded, 0 filesize, no pathname, etc.  Matybe a difference in your upload forms?  Check them, maybe add them to your question. Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Value for "error" is 2 .. that might indicate an error. `getErrorMessage` probably has more info

Comment: can you add the form code for the user form where it is changing the mime-type, because application/octet-stream is default mime-type

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, just realized what happened: there was a size cap for the  avatar upload that was not the same on the products. Closing the question